# Error: Failed to patch App Service configuration

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, azure-appservice

I am deploying a docker image from ACR to windows based App Service using Azure DevOps release pipeline (with Azure Web App on Container Deploy task). But getting the error as

"*Error: Failed to patch App Service '[App Service Name]' configuration. Error: BadRequest - The parameter DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL has an invalid value. Unexpected error when connecting to the registry. Cannot find available registry. https://[ACR Name].azurecr.io (CODE: 400)* *Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)*"

*Both App Service and ACR are using private endpoint. We are using self hosted agent for our pipeline.*

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Any linked documents do you follow? What's the DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL you have input?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this question?

Comment: @Jane, Still facing the same issue. But if the ACR was configured with public endpoints, I am able to deploy the image to App Service. So ACR is configured with private endpoints I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trouble shooting advice:

Please check the value of `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL` in your ARM template or config file.

What's more, if you are using ARM template, try to add `"reserved": true` to your `properties`.

Comment: I am not using ARM template

Comment: @VKD Could you please provide the sample script of your config file? So that people can  investigate the question further :) A tip: Don't write the script in the comments, edit your question instead.